# Fall detection and BLE button press event not working seperatly

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating a BLE android app.The app will make alarm when the BLE device button is pressed or dropped(Fall detection).Everything worked until I added the fall detection along with button press.Now the problem is whenever the app runs if I pressed the button I will get an alrm.After that  It will not work for fall detection.Again If I droped the button at app launch then I will get an alarm,after that no alarm for button press.

Here is my **onServicesDiscovered** in BluetoothLEservice.java

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
               // broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED, deviceAddress, status);
                // Do APP verification as soon as service discovered.
                try {
                    appVerification(gatt, getGattChar(gatt, Constants.SIMPLE_SERVICE,Constants.CHAR_APP_VERIFICATION),Constants.NEW_APP_VERIFICATION_VALUE);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Log.e(,"exception with app verify:" + e.getMessage());
                }

                for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
                    if ((service == null) || (service.getUuid() == null)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (Constants.SIMPLE_SERVICE.equals(service.getUuid())) {
//                       
                        // Write Emergency key press
                        enableForDetect(gatt,service.getCharacteristic(Constants.CHAR_DETECTION_CONFIG),Constants.ENABLE_KEY_LONGPRESS_DETECTION_VALUE);
                        // Set notification for emergency key press and fall detection
                        setCharacteristicNotification(gatt,service.getCharacteristic(Constants.CHAR_DETECTION_NOTIFY),true);
                    }
                    else if (Constants.SIMPLE_SERVICE.equals(service.getUuid())){


                        if (db.getValue(Common.FALL_DETECTION).equals(Common.TRUE)){
                            enableForDetect(gatt,service.getCharacteristic(Constants.CHAR_DETECTION_CONFIG),Constants.ENABLE_FALL_KEY_DETECTION_VALUE);
                            setCharacteristicNotification(gatt,service.getCharacteristic(Constants.CHAR_DETECTION_NOTIFY),true);
                        }

                    }
```

In my **onCharacteristicChanged** I will redirect two of these events to my alert activity according to the Keyvalue.
Any help is appriciated.Please ask if any further explanation needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a mistake in my Gattconstant class. For Button press it need to be write

```
public static final byte[] ENABLE_KEY_DETECTION_VALUE = new byte[]{(byte) 2};
```

For fall detection it need to be write

```
public static final byte[] ENABLE_FALL_KEY_DETECTION_VALUE = new byte[]{(byte) 6};
```

I writed 4 instead of 6.